# Request for migration of a question - [resolved]

Tags: support, migration

Edit:  another user has identified a canonical question on the other site which would make mine a duplicate, so this is probably not the best candidate for migration.

---

Recently, I asked [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336621/weird-question-is-arrived-technically-deponent/336694#336694) which I believed would be on-topic for this site, but has attracted a lot of feedback which tends to misunderstand what I was actually asking.  This, and the fact that a high-rep user suggested re-asking this question there, lead me to believe that the question would be a better fit for the ELU site.

The issue is that I don't see any way of migrating the question myself, and I don't want to *delete* the original as that would also delete everyone else's comments and answer.  Multiple users have contributed interesting and thoughtful content to the question which, although not what I was looking for, might very well be helpful to future viewers.  Could someone with the required privileges please migrate this question to the other site?  I didn't include a link because of the meta effect, but the question should be easy to find as it's my only one so far.  Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have migrated your question to EL&U.

FWIW, I too consider that question better suited to EL&U as it doesn't reflect the needs of a language learner, as nobody needs to know what category of word "arrived" is in that context to be able to produce or understand it perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, @gotube!  I can't believe how fast someone answered the question over on the other site :)